# Can I install openstack cloud software on my ubuntu 12.04 lts machine?

Tags: 12.04, installation, openstack

I want to install openstack cloud software on my ubuntu 12.04 LTS machine. Help needed.

Answer (score 0):

There is official documentation from [OpenStack](http://docs.openstack.org/)

[OpenStack Installation Guide for Ubuntu 12.04 (LTS)](http://docs.openstack.org/trunk/install-guide/install/apt/content/)